# Totalling values with the same order name

Tags: sql-order-by, echo

I have table in mysql with columns "name" and "views". I want sum views from serial whose name is in "name" column and display list of serials with views by echo from the most popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this query:

```
SELECT name, SUM(views) as total_views 
FROM serial
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total_views DESC
```